# Update conditionally one OR two field - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

There are many solutions how to update with condition. But I have found none with updating one OR two fields. I want to update the stopdate if it is older than today. Otherwise only the startdate.

```
UPDATE table SET
CASE 
WHEN stopdate < today
THEN startdate=today, stopdate=today
ELSE startdate=today 
END
```

Possible?

TIA,

Comment: You could just `SET startdate = today, stopdate = GREATEST(today, stopdate)`

Comment: this updates every row..

Comment: @BenH technically, yes. But if there are no triggers involved it doesn't really matter. Otherwise two separate `UPDATE` statements would be required (but OP is already aware of that).